# Bash elif prints out "/Users/USER/Desktop/SCRIPT.sh: line 30: [ 4: command not found"

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a script that build PPSSPP ( doesn't matter for the question ) and provide a GUI. So for example if the user chooses ( types ) 1 then i'd run `git pull --rebase` . It works for some options and doesn't for some. And always prints out `/Users/USER/Desktop/SCRIPT.sh: line 38: [ 1: command not found` 3 times for every line that has "elif" in it

Here's enough of the script to reproduce the problem ( Obviously i cd in the right dir and have options for others etc. )

```
printf "Please choose an option : "
read option

if [ $option = 0 ]
then
    exit

elif [ $option = 1 ]
then
    git pull --rebase
fi
```

Comment: The error message suggests that isn't actually a space between `[` and `$option` -- my guess is that it's a nonbreaking space, which the shell will treat as part of a "word", rather than a separator between words (like a real space would be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to always quote all your vars. Also, the error lies in that you are not comparing values in the conditionals, you are using the assign operator instead. Use the proper comparison operators:

```
printf "Please choose an option : "
read option

if [ "$option" -eq 0 ]
then
    exit

elif [ "$option" -eq 1 ]
then
    git pull --rebase
fi
```

Comment: This wasn't the problem. Inside `[ ]`, the `=` operator does string comparison, not assignment, and if you're not sure `$option` is an integer, string comparison is actually more appropriate.

Comment: The string comparison operator is `==`, not `=`.

Comment: No. From the [POSIX standard for the `test` (aka `[`) command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html): "s1 =  s2
True if the strings s1 and s2 are identical; otherwise, false." "==" does not occur in the standard, but some shells (e.g. bash) allow it as a synonym. Mind you, `=` is used for assignment and `==` for comparison in arithmetic contexts, but that's different.

Comment: :-O Thanks for the clarification. I was really convinced about the meaning of `=` in conditionals. Then, your guess is probably quite more probable than mine.